# Asp.Net development server file path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How should I setup the vs development server to have a possibility to get the files by relative path? I mean, that when I type a path to a file: "somefile.txt" the server should search in the web project folder, but now in the folder where asp.net dev server has been setuped

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might help you:

If you want to get the path to a folder - an image folder for example -:

```
String pathToImgFolder = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/imgs/");
```

Check the [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx) documentation for more details.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @valerii.sverdlik select this or any other answer (if they helped) as the 'selected' answer (green check).

Answer (score 0):

On the server side I usually go for:

```
Server.MapPath(@"~\your\relative\path")
```

while on the client side (if the project is not a root site ):

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

if the project is a root site (i.e - some.site.com) then on the view I don't really worry about it and just use the site's relative path.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but this is just a personal preference and you should not really used it unless you're absoluty sure of it. Although is personal preference, I've also had to, personally, refactor a lot of broken links. So for views the first option is the best way to your files through relative path.